# Filter campaigns for date

Tags: angularjs, date

How do I filter the campaigns for current date. I'm starting with Angular.

```
// Controller
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('list.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.campanha = response.data.campaigns;
    });
});
```

In my view

```
<article class="campanha" ng-repeat="campaign in campanha | searchFor:searchString">
    <a href="#single/{{campaign.id}}" title="{{ campaign.name }}">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ campaign.imageAddressXhdpi }}" alt="{{ campaign.name }}">
    </a>
</article>
```

link rest: http://104.236.89.155:8080/guru/rest/campaign/list

Comment: can you be more specific??

Comment: Please post sample data, Because that link doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see anything having to do with a date in any of your code.  This question is much too vague.

Comment: Excuse me, what I need is to list all capanhas from the current date. See the link http://guruapp.com.br/gurudev/#/ he's bringing last year's posts. Have script on github https://github.com/eliasfaical/guruapp